# Using GLM unproject to convert mouse position into 3d coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew, glm-math

I am trying to draw a cone on the screen that follows the mouse, using OpenGL and GLM (also GLEW and GLFW, but they are not important for the details of this question).

Currently, I get the mouse position using glfwGetCursorPos. I then make that into a 3-vector, setting the z-position to be 0 (for testing purposes, I may well change this later on), and create a vector specifying the lower left corner at 0,0, and the width and height at 1024 and 768 (which are indeed the width and height of the window I create). I then pass in my modelview matrix and projection matrix to the glm::unProject method, to get the projected x and y coordinates, and update the positions of the appropriate vertices of the cone that is supposed to track the mouse (the cone is reset to be centered at 0, 0, 0 after each frame). I do not use the projected z coordinate because using that made the cone just disappear. Currently, the code works well because I am multiplying the position increments by 200, a number I found experimentally made the cone sync to my mouse. I am not sure why just adding the projected coordinates without having to multiply them wouldn't work, but it didn't - the cone moved very slowly / small increments compared to how far I moved my mouse. I am almost sure multiplying by a random number is not the proper way to do this and probably will not be portable as this number will maybe be different depending on frame rate, window size, OS, or something. Any ideas?

```
    double xpos, ypos;
    glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xpos, &ypos);

    glm::vec3 pos = glm::vec3(xpos, ypos, 0.0f);
    glm::vec4 viewportdata = glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1024.0f, 768.0f);

    glm::vec3 un = glm::unProject(pos, View*Model, Projection, viewportdata);
    float xp = un[0], yp = un[1];

    for (int i = 0; i < 8*9; i++) { // update positions of vertices
        if (i % 3 == 0)
            g_vertex_buffer_data[i+size-8*9] += xp*200;
        else if (i % 3 == 1)
            g_vertex_buffer_data[i+size-8*9] += yp*200;
    }
```

Comment: Is it needed to be moved in 3D space? If not, have you tried using 2D projection with `glOrtho`?

Comment: @Keugyeol Eventually, I will need the mouse to click on objects in 3d space. It's fine if it displays in 2D space though.

Comment: *"I then pass in my modelview matrix and projection matrix to the glm::unProject method, to get the projected x and y coordinates"* -- The coordinates you get back from `unProject` are not projected coordinates. Quite the opposite in fact. `unProject` undoes the viewport transform, then it undoes division by W, then it undoes projection, and then it undoes the viewing and modelling transformations. If you want to know the projected coordinates, then you are using the wrong function - all you need to do is undo the viewport and division by W and you will have clip-space coordinates.

Comment: Passing identity matrices for ModelView and Projection will actually do that for you.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman
I passed in the identity matrices, but I ran into the same problem - though I needed to change the *200 to *9. Still, this seems like it means the behavior is still incorrect.

Comment: @Keugyeol
I don't know if I understand glOrtho correctly, but it sounds like it transforms everything? I want to keep the rest of my "world" displaying the same way in 3D, but just get the mouse coordinates in 2D.

Comment: Not to be rude, but I think you may not understand coordinate space transformations in general. `glOrtho` sets up a projection matrix, which describes how your 3D scene is projected onto your 2D image plane. The coordinates remain 3D even after projection, the 3rd coordinate is what is stored in the depth buffer (after depth range) and the other 2 are effectively your window's x,y coordinates (after viewport). If you've not already seen this, [this site might help](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman
Thanks, that site was quite helpful. Now that I *think* I understand what all the functions actually stand for / do:

What I would do to get the (x,y) is undo the viewport transform, then undivide by w, then undo the perspective projection and do an orthographic projection instead. Does this sound correct?

Comment: However, I actually want to allow the user to be able to move the mouse in 3d-space. Since many 3D coordinates correspond to the same 2D coordinate, given a viewport point, I actually want to get the point (after the perspective projection occurs): (x,y,z) corresponding to that viewport point, given a user's choice of z.

Comment: So, to translate an entire object in a vertex array to the mouse, is there any easier way than to undo every single transformation on the viewport coordinates, then to add those unprojected coordinates to the corresponding coordinates in the vertex array, and then to retransform all those coordinates?